# Function for flipping the sign of a number

Tags: .net, floating-point, double

How can I change the sign of a number?

`abs();` will not return me a negative when the input is positive, correct? I need the opposite sign.

Comment: Is your question about .net or the C++ Standard library?

Comment: What is wrong with multiplying by -1 ? Basic arithmetics.

Comment: @Oded: What's wrong with using the unary minus operator? `-x`.

Comment: Before people go downvoting answers suggesting the use of `Abs`, keep in mind this question was poorly written, and suggested quite strongly the use of `Abs`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just multiply by -1:

```
double d = 1.2345;
double opposite = d * -1;
```

Comment: wow @ how the simplest answer solves
i was bulding string parsers to add or remove the -

Answer (score 11):

Dude. Minus.

```
double d = 1.1234;
double opposite = -d;
```

Answer (score 1):

<s>Check out `Math.Abs`</s> (answer to previous version of question).

Use the negative sign:

```
var answer = -amount;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is too obvious:

```
n = -n
```

You should use:

```
n = ~--n;
```

..or, if you like the OR bitwise, use:

```
 n = (0xffffffff ^ n) + 1;
```

...if that +1 is too obvious for you, this is a sure bet:

```
n ^= 0xffffffff;
int m;
for (m = 1; m != 0 && ((n & m) != 0); m <<= 1);
n |= m;
if (m == 0) n = m;
else for (m >>= 1; m != 0; n ^= m, m >>=1);
```

...there's also the option for people who want to make sure none of their processing power goes unused:

```
public int invert(int n) {
  Random r = new Random();
  while (true) {
    int s = r.nextInt();
    if ((s + n) == 0) {
      return s;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

in C++, simply `abs(x)` which is in `math.h`
This is the [Absolute Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value) function.

Comment: Actually, `abs` is defined in `<cstdlib>` and is overloaded for `int` and `double`. In `<cmath>` you'll find `fabs`, which is overloaded for `float`, `double`, and `long double`.